# How can i use RotateAnimation to rotate a circle?

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I want my circle image (ImageView) to rotate as the user touch and drag it. If the user drags it to the right, it should spin right and vice versa. Like when you spin a DJ disc, if you know what i mean. I've played around a bit with OnTouchListener and RotateAnimation but i'm getting nowhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could show your attempt, with details on whats not working.

Comment: In fact i don't even know how to proceed with what i want. I just need some ideas how it can be accomplished.

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume you have `ImageView mCircle` which you want to rotate. You have to use `RotateAnimation` to rotate it. In `OnTouch` method determine the angle where user's finger is.

For example, in your main activity do the following

```
private ImageView mCircle;
private double mCurrAngle = 0;
private double mPrevAngle = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);
    mCircle.setOnTouchListener(this); // Your activity should implement OnTouchListener
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    final float xc = mCircle.getWidth() / 2;
    final float yc = mCircle.getHeight() / 2;

    final float x = event.getX();
    final float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        mCircle.clearAnimation();
        mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
        mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
        animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0);
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : {
        mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle = 0;
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}

private void animate(double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long durationMillis) {
    final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) fromDegrees, (float) toDegrees,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(durationMillis);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    mCircle.startAnimation(rotate);
}
```

Comment: I have modified your code to work like knob which will be between -120 and 120 angle. But whenever i ActionDown it move back to it's orignal position, I want to save last touched angle and whenever i ActionDown it will be on the last position.

Comment: @Nepster, try commenting the `clearAnimation()` call.

Comment: @vasart, commenting the clearAnimation() does not help.