# rotating image on its center

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I tried methods on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8996581/1389581 but none of them worked for me.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_arround_center);

        try {
            radarView.startAnimation(animation);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.i(ProcessActivity.str_logCaptionName_ProcessActivity, "radar animation ex : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="45"
  android:toDegrees="45"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:startOffset="0"/>

</set>
```

gives null exception. When I use the matrix method, application gives fatal error and crashes.

I don't want to change bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:[How can i use RotateAnimation to rotate a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045832/how-can-i-use-rotateanimation-to-rotate-a-circle/14297097#14297097)

No sure if it what are looking for, but it works.

Comment: it gives null exception again :(