# Android : rotate an image clockwise and anticlockwise with two simple buttons

Tags: android, image, rotation

I have two simple buttons and one image:

[image]

clockwise button click event ==> rotates the image 1 degree in clockwise

anticlockwise button click event ==> rotates the image 1 degree in anticlockwise

how can I do that?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045832/how-can-i-use-rotateanimation-to-rotate-a-circle/14297097#14297097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image.setRotation(angle)
```

works for API 11 and above.

-Edit
Matrix works for lower API levels:

for clockwise:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.postRotate(angle++, image.getDrawable().getBounds().width() / 2, image.getDrawable().getBounds().height() / 2);
image.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

for anticlockwise, you can replace angle++ to angle--

Comment: its not what I want. for example when user click on clockwise button the angle of image is +1 and by clicking again the angle is +2 , .... .  unfortunately I'm developing my app for API level 8 and above.