# How to connect a rotating ImageView to MediaPlayer so that it rotates when MediaPlayer is playing in android

Tags: android, media-player, image-rotation

As in the title, I want to make a rotating disc which will rotate when I hit play on mediaplayer. Here is the code for my ImageView (for now it moves onTouch) :

```
public class DjDiscsHandler {
    public static double mCurrAngle = 0;
    public static double mPrevAngle = 0;

    public static void Discs(final ImageView djDisc, final String side) {
        djDisc.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final float xc = djDisc.getWidth() / 2;
                final float yc = djDisc.getHeight() / 2;

                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();

                switch(side) {
                    case "left":
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                            mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
                            mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
                            Log.i("Current Angle", "" + mCurrAngle);
                            animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0, djDisc);
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                                mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
                                break;
                            }
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                                mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
                                mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));
                                animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0, djDisc);
                                break;
                            }
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                                mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void animate(double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long durationMillis, final ImageView djDiscLeft) {
        final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) fromDegrees, (float) toDegrees,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(durationMillis);
        rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);
        djDiscLeft.startAnimation(rotate);
    }
}
```

I found the code for this here: [How can i use RotateAnimation to rotate a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045832/how-can-i-use-rotateanimation-to-rotate-a-circle)

Now I want to add it to my mediaplyer handler:

```
            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Deck.mediaplayerReadyLeft) {
                    Deck.mediaplayerLeft.start();
                    double mCurrAngle = 0;
                    while(Deck.mediaplayerLeft.isPlaying()) {
                        DjDiscsHandler.animate(mCurrAngle, mCurrAngle + 1, 0, Deck.djDiscLeft);
                        mCurrAngle++;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately the program freezes when I press play and crushes a few moments later.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are entering a `while()` loop which is halting the rest of your app while it processes. Remember, you're not on a separate thread here, so while the code in your `while()` loop executes, nothing else is. You're essentially trying to do a makeshift "draw" loop to perform the animation, but you can't just stop everything else to perform that one action. Instead, you would want to *trigger* an animation to start when the play button is pressed. Try this instead...

In your `anim` folder inside your `res` folder, add this rotate anim xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Then when it comes time to start the animation (i.e., when you hit the play button), you would execute something like this...

```
Animation rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_anim);
ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
yourImageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

To stop the rotation animation, you can just call `clearAnimation()` on your ImageView.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: Is there a way to stop the animation without clearing it? When I clear it, the ImageView returns to its original position and I'd like it to stay the way it stopped.

Comment: You can try setting `fillAfter=true` and `fillEnabled=true` in the anim xml and see if that does the trick.

Comment: It doesn't work, after I call clearAnimation() it still returns to the original position

Comment: How about calling `setFillAfter(true)` and `setFillEnabled(true)` on `rotateAnimation` itself in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Considered using a gif showing a rotating image?